# Command wasn't called in deploy file use Capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano3

- I had a problem when i run `cap production deploy`.
- I want to run a command restart unicorn server same as ubuntu service when `cap production deploy` finished.
- But problem was here that it didn't run this command `/etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app restart` when command `cap production deploy` finished and the server didn't restart.
- And i must `ssh` to server and start unicorn server `/etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app restart` manually, so i didn't know the reason.
- I research a lot of documents and topics and try a lot, but i was unsuccessful. Hope everybody can help me. Thank you very much.

This is my `deploy.rb`

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:****/my_app.git'
set :branch, 'master'

set :rvm_type, :auto
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.1@my_app'

set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
set :bundle_dir, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }
set :bundle_flags, nil
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')
set :bundle_binstubs, nil
set :bundle_roles, :all
set :app_path, '/var/www/my_app/current/'

set :scm, :git
set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, true
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug
set :keep_releases, 5

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end

  task :restart_unicorn do
    on roles(:all) do
      begin 
        puts "INFO #{Time.now} starting unicorn"
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app restart"
      rescue => e
        puts "ERROR #{Time.now} error with #{e.inspect}"
      end
    end
  end
  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup", "deploy:restart_unicorn"
end
```

- Update: @Deep: I tried add `sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app restart` and it didn't run anyway. Does anybody explain for me why it didn't run ? Thank you.

Comment: did you try adding `sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn restart` in it may be permission problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, but i have two reasons to know, it didn't run.
 First, if it had permission problem, it will throw an error, because i put it inside `begin ... rescue `, but when i run `cap production deploy` finished, it didn't throw any errors.
Second, i put as `set :use_sudo, true` in deploy.rb file. I think it will run with `sudo permission`.

So, i will try it right away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I've just tried adding `sudo`, but it didn't run. So, do you have any idea or solutions for this case ? Thank you very much.